# Do I need a dovecot.socket?

Tags: linux, email, dovecot, systemd

My email server with dovecot works fine. I turned off IPv6 and encountered the following error in syslog:

```
systemd[1]: [/lib/systemd/system/dovecot.socket:8] \
    Failed to parse address value, ignoring: [::]:143
```

I commented all IPv6 settings in `dovecot.service` out, performed a `systemctl daemon-reload` and now the file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server activation socket

[Socket]
#dovecot expects separate IPv4 and IPv6 sockets
#BindIPv6Only=ipv6-only
ListenStream=0.0.0.0:143
#ListenStream=[::]:143
ListenStream=0.0.0.0:993
#ListenStream=[::]:993
KeepAlive=true

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

The current state of `dovecot.service` is `Active: inactive (dead)`:

```
● dovecot.socket - Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server activation socket
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dovecot.socket; enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sun 2018-08-12 14:39:42 CEST; 14min ago
   Listen: 0.0.0.0:143 (Stream)
           0.0.0.0:993 (Stream)
```

But, when I try to start the service, I get the following error messages:

```
systemd[1]: Starting Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server activation socket.
systemd[1]: Socket service dovecot.service already active, refusing.
systemd[1]: Failed to listen on Dovecot IMAP/POP3 email server activation socket.
```

Everything works fine, dovecot listens on all desired ports. Could someone please explain to me:

- Why can't I start the `dovecot.socket`?
- Do I need the `dovecot.socket` at all?

Comment: No, you don't need the socket activation.

Answer (score 2):

Dovecot probably already listens in the sockets, this is a common configuration for dovecot. Try this command to verify.

```
ss -ntpl | grep -e :143 -e :993
```

If dovecot already listens on these ports, then systemd can't also listen on these ports. If you have dovecot listening, you don't need `dovecot.socket`.